# Deserialization issue in abtract class with having a relation with an another class

Tags: angular, spring

I am developing an application angular 6 / spring boot. I have the relationships below:
When I try to persist a Quote object it works if the Customer object is null. But if I want to persist a Quote object with customer I get the message :

@Entity
   @Inheritance
   public abstract class Customer implements Serializable{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idCustomer;
@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String code;
private String name;
private String address;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String city;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private List<Order> orders;
private byte status;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private List<Quote> quote;
@JoinColumn(name="country")
@ManyToOne
private Country country;

@Entity
public class Individual extends Customer{

private String firstname;
private String gender;

@Entity
public class Company extends Customer implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@NotNull
private String legalForm;

@Entity
public class Quote implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idQuote;
private LocalDate dateQuote;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="quote", 
cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<QuoteLine> items;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_customer",nullable=false)
private Customer customer;
```

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.pam.entities.Customer` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Answer (score 0):

You need to use default constructor and setter getter methods. Did you write that?

Comment: A constructor where ?

Comment: Inside you POJO class Company.ajav Quote.java

Comment: Yes I have default constructor and setters/getters in all classes

Comment: Ok.. Can you try by putting given annotation on Company.java class at class level.
@JsonDeserialize(as = Company.class)

Comment: I try it but I have the same error :  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 460] (through reference chain: com.pam.entities.Quote["customer"])] with root cause
....